# How to add multiple languages on Samsung Store?

Tags: android, translation, store

I have an app published on the Samsung Store with the language default as English. But I want to add multiple languages (like Portuguese/Korean...) in the store, how I do it?

PS: My app already has the multiple strings.xml in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer on the FAQ, to add a new language I needed to go in App Informations, set the mode to Advanced and then click on add button.